# Running JS on page load to draw a canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am working on a new graph for my site, using CSS3/HTML5 (canvas tag). Everything is going great so far, but I have one problem: Right now, the canvas loads blank, and the user has to click on a link to trigger the JS that draws the graph.

Its been a while since I had JS that I wanted to run immediately, so I figured I would ask what the best way to handle this would be.

P.S. Due to compatibility issues with one of the frameworks I use, I cannot use JQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An unobtrusive solution

```
window.onload = function() {
    // ... do stuff
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run JS immediately from the body element's onLoad attribute:

```
<body onload="myFunc();">
```